# Learning Java and the For loop is not rendering

Tags: java

I created this `PassworField` method below. the intension is to break out of the loop if user enters the correct password `hello`. It should loop 5 time before blocking the user. It does break out if the user enter the correct password first time but doesn't break out when user enter wrong password first then correct on the second try. It just loops 5 time even I input the correct pasword then blockes. I would appreciate if you can help..driving me nuts...

```
public class LoginPage {


         static String password = "hello";
         static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
         static String input = scn.nextLine();


        public static void PasswordField() {
            System.out.println("Enter the password");
            for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
                if (password.equals(input)) {
                        System.out.println("You are In");
                             break;
                }
                   else if(!input.equals(password)) {
                            System.out.println("Wrong, Please Enter the Password again:");
                            scn.nextLine();
                    }
                else {
                       System.out.println("You are Blocked sucker. call helpdesk");
                }


            }
                            scn.close();
         }
```

Comment: Putting a blocking method like 'readLine' on a static field is a horrible horrible idea. At the absolute least make input local to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is updating `input` with the new value. Additionally, the logic for being blocked should be *after* the for loop is finished.

```java
 public static void PasswordField() {
        System.out.println("Enter the password");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (password.equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("You are In");
                scn.close();
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong, Please Enter the Password again:");
                input = scn.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You are Blocked sucker. call helpdesk");
        scn.close();
}
```

Comment: I love this answer. but for some reason the firrt Sysout "Enter the password" is not printing when i run. it only prints after i give a input....

Comment: @RahenCHoudhury the first call to scanner.nextLine() happens when you initialize the class, because you are calling it in the field declaration. Put the call after you print the line.

Comment: I did but still not working. please look at the code below is that what you mean? @JCOC611 public static void PasswordField() {
            System.out.println("Enter the password");
            for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
                if (password.equals(input)) {
                    System.out.println("You are In");
                    scn.close();
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong, Please Enter the Password again:");
                    input = scn.nextLine();

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the user has exceeded the maximum number of allowed attempts once the loop terminates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputPassword();
    }

    public static void inputPassword() {
        final Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String password = "hello";
        String input;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the password: ");
            input = scn.nextLine();
            if (password.equals(input)) {
                System.out.println("You are In");
                break;
            } else if (i < 5) {
                System.out.println("Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.");
            }
        }
        if (i > 5) {
            System.out.println("You are blocked as you have exceeded the maximum limit.");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the password: 1
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: 2
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: 3
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: 4
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: 5
You are blocked as you have exceeded the maximum limit.
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the password: 1
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: Hello
Wrong, Please Enter the Password again.
Enter the password: hello
You are In
```

**Some other important notes:**

1. Do not close a `Scanner` for `System.in` as it closes `System.in` as well.
2. Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the method, `PasswordField` should be named as `passwordField` as per the naming conventions.